# Why I got this error message when I change the proxy? 'Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED'

Tags: python, automation, proxy, bots, playwright

I wrote a automation bot with python playwright and I want to change my proxy. But I got error `Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED https://www.passo.com.tr/tr/giris` when I try to connect to the website. I use https protocol. Website's link is = "https://www.passo.com.tr/tr/giris".
Can you help me ?

My code is:

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import asyncio

proxy_pool = [
    {"server": "20.24.43.214:80"},
    {"server": "46.245.77.53:3128"},
]

async def main():
    for _ in range(2): 
        proxy = proxy_pool[_]

        async with async_playwright() as p:
            browser = await p.chromium.launch(proxy=proxy)
            context = await browser.new_context()
            page = await context.new_page()

            try:
                await page.goto("https://www.passo.com.tr/tr/giris", timeout=5000)
                text_content = await page.content()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

            await context.close()
            await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

I expect to connect with different proxies. Because website has got a bot protection.

Comment: What OS are you using? I assume by this error you are running on Chrome too?

Comment: Yes, windows and chrome

Comment: If you try this without the use of playwright does it connect okay?